# How can I show my Navbar.Brand image on mobile screens?

Tags: html, css, typescript, navbar, react-bootstrap

I have created a Navbar using React Boostrap however the brand image disappears on mobile screens. See below.

**Navbar on desktop**
[image: Navbar on desktop]

**Navbar on mobile**
[image: Navbar on mobile]

As you can see the logo goes into the menu when on mobile. How can I overwrite this so that the logo is on the navbar when on mobile?

**See code below**

```
<div>
              <Navbar className="planted-navbar" variant="dark" expand="lg">
                <Container className="navbar-container">
                  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                  <Navbar.Collapse id="planted-navbar-collapse">
                    <Nav className="ml-auto">
                      <Navbar.Brand href="home" bsPrefix="planted-navbar-brand">
                      <img
                        src={plantedLogo}
                        width="150px"
                        // height="70px"
                        className="d-inline-block align-top"
                        alt="Restorify logo"
                      />
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                      <NavDropdown title="Missions" id="missions-dropdown">
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="county-select">Select a County</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="mission-select">Select a Mission</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </NavDropdown>
                      <NavDropdown title="Dashboard" id="trees-dropdown">
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="dashboard">My Dashboard</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="subscribeToTree">Subscribe To Tree</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </NavDropdown>
                      <NavDropdown title="Posts" id="posts-dropdown">
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="post-tile">Posts</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="posts-to-write">Posts to Write</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="write-a-post">Write a Tree Post</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="login-mission-post" id="login-item">Write a Mission Post</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </NavDropdown>
                      <Nav.Link href="leaderboard" id="leaderboard-link">Leaderboard</Nav.Link>
                      <Nav.Link href="about" id="about-link">About</Nav.Link>
                      <Nav.Link href="login" id="login-link">Login</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                  </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Container>
              </Navbar>
      </div>
```

Comment: You have to post your code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I just get a line of text when I run the code you supplied. (try running the code you posted in a browser)

If you can put your css, html, and script on a site like jsfiddle.net to post a functioning example to duplicate the issue, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless i'm misunderstanding something, just move the `Navbar.Brand` outside of the toggle area

```
<div>
  <Navbar className="planted-navbar" variant="dark" expand="lg">
    <Container className="navbar-container">
      <Navbar.Brand href="home" bsPrefix="planted-navbar-brand">
        <img
          src={plantedLogo}
          width="150px"
          // height="70px"
          className="d-inline-block align-top"
          alt="Restorify logo"
        />
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="planted-navbar-collapse">
        <Nav className="ml-auto">
          <NavDropdown title="Missions" id="missions-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="county-select">Select a County</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="mission-select">Select a Mission</NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
          <NavDropdown title="Dashboard" id="trees-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="dashboard">My Dashboard</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="subscribeToTree">Subscribe To Tree</NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
          <NavDropdown title="Posts" id="posts-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="post-tile">Posts</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="posts-to-write">Posts to Write</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="write-a-post">Write a Tree Post</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="login-mission-post" id="login-item">Write a Mission Post</NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
          <Nav.Link href="leaderboard" id="leaderboard-link">Leaderboard</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="about" id="about-link">About</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="login" id="login-link">Login</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Container>
  </Navbar>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew it was an easy solution just couldn't find it. Thanks so much